# How does one automatically format a returned dynamodb item so that it can be put back into dynamodb as-is or slightly modified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

dynamodb yields an item in a string format:

```py
cdb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
table = db.Table('my-table')
response = table.scan()
my_data = response['Items']
foo = my_data[0]
print(foo)

#  {'theID': 'fffff8f-dfsadfasfds-fsdsaf', 'theNumber': Decimal('1')}
```

Now, when I treat this like a black-box `unit`, do nothing, and return it to the db via put-item, I'll get many errors indicating none of the values in the dictionary are the expected type:

```
cdb.put_item(TableName='my-table', Item=foo, ReturnValues="ALL_OLD")

# many errors
```

I'd like to rely on `boto3` to do everything and avoid manipulating the values if possible. Is there a utility available that will convert a response item into the format it needs to be to be placed back in the db?

Comment: Staying "many errors" is not going to help us fix your issue. Please share the full stack trace of the errors you are getting.

Comment: The boto3 DynamoDB resource-level interface Table auto-marshalls values between native DynamoDB types and native Python types. The client-level interface does not. Use one interface or the other. Don't mix them. Compare the Item passed to [client-level put_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item) with the same Item in [resource-level put_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your table resource to write items because you also use it to read.

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
table.put_item(Item=foo, ReturnValues="ALL_OLD")
```

You're reading the data using the higher-level resource API, which maps many native Python Types to DynamoDB types, and trying to write using the lower-level client API, which doesn't do that.

The simple solution is also to use the resource-API to write, and it will perform the mappings.

(I'm inferring this based on your method signature for `put_item`, the question is not overly clear...)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is also a serializer that can be used:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer
```